# Baire's Category Theorem fails for uncountable intersection of open, dense subsets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples, baire-category

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but equals $\cap_{x\in\mathbb{R}\cap\mathbb{Z}^c}[(-\infty,x)\cup(x,\infty)]$, where each $[(-\infty,x)\cup(x,\infty)]$ is dense and open in $\mathbb{R}$, can I use this to show the necessity of the intersection being countable in the Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: You should try to correct your question : $\mathbb{Z}$ can't contain dense sets, so it can't be a union of them. However $\mathbb{Z}$ is an $F_\sigma$

Comment: Edited question to intersection.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any set of reals whatsoever is the intersection of a family of dense open sets: for $x\not\in A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, let $D_x=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{x\}$; this is dense and open, and clearly we have $$A=\bigcap_{x\not\in A} D_x.$$ So it is absolutely essential to the Baire Category Theorem that the collection of dense open sets in question be countable.

---

EDIT: it may be more intuitive to think of the converse task - expressing any set of reals as a *union* of *closed nowhere-dense* sets. The idea is identical, but it might be clearer: we always have $$A=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\},$$
 and every singleton $\{a\}$ is closed and nowhere dense, so any set of reals is a union of closed nowhere-dense sets.

---

EDIT $2$: In response to your most recent edit, yes, writing (for example) $\mathbb{Z}$ as an intersection of open dense sets shows that countability is necessary. An even better example though: what is $$\bigcap_{r\in\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{r\})?$$

Comment: So I should write $\mathbb{Z}=\cap_{x\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}}[(-\infty,x)\cup(x,\infty)]$?  I had written this initially but deleted it because I thought it was wrong.

Comment: @HBHSU What do you mean? $\mathbb{Z}=\bigcap_{y\not\in\mathbb{Z}} \{x: x\not=y\}$ is straightforward enough.

Comment: Ok, the counterexample should be the empty set.

Comment: @HBHSU Yes, the set at the end of my answer is the emptyset.